# Client code for sending and receiving messages

Tags: c++, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Can someone please tell me how can I write a C++ client using the Firebase Cloud Messaging SDK for C++ ? Please point me too a tutorial or GitHub link or some kind of help in the answers. Thank you.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/cpp/client

Does it fit your needs?

Comment: This is for using the c++ sdk in Android app right ? I want to use FCM client as a standalone client on my Ubuntu PC